# How to remove nan when extend multilevel column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

I would like to extend the following multilevel

```
first   tech_one                      ... tech_four       etc       mtc
second    ch0_b0    ch1_b0    ch2_b0  ...       ch5                    
0       1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  ...  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038
1       0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  ... -0.742165  2.269755 -1.454366
2       0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  ...  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327
```

Into

```
   tech_one                      ... tech_four       etc       mtc
        ch0       ch1       ch2  ...       ch5         _         _
         b0        b0        b0  ...                  
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  ...  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038
1  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  ... -0.742165  2.269755 -1.454366
2  0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  ...  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327
```

The following code is drafted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
np.random.seed(0)


arrays = [["tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_two", "tech_two", "tech_two",
           "tech_two",'tech_three','tech_three','tech_four','etc','mtc'],
          ["ch0_b0", "ch1_b0", "ch2_b0", "ch3_b0", "ch0", "ch1", "ch2", "ch3","ch1",'ch3','ch5','','']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)), names=["first", "second"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, len(arrays[0])), columns=index)
tup=[(e[0],*re.split('_',e[1])) for e in df.columns]
remove_nan=[tuple('_' if x == '' else x for x in x) for x in tup]

df.columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(remove_nan)
```

which produced the folllowing

```
   tech_one                      ... tech_four       etc       mtc
        ch0       ch1       ch2  ...       ch5         _         _
         b0        b0        b0  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  ...  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038
1  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  ... -0.742165  2.269755 -1.454366
2  0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  ...  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327
```

As can be seen above, the `NaN` is still there despite being removed using the line

```
remove_nan=[tuple('_' if x == '' else x for x in x) for x in tup]
```

May I know to handle this issue?

Comment: The reason for `NaN` is because you have tuples with different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comment, the reason for `NaN` is different length tuples, you can just create the list of tuples with equal length, taking the length of maximum length tuples from the list, and having empty string `''` to enlarge the tuple.

```py
n = len(max(remove_nan, key=len))
remove_nan=[t+('',)*(n-len(t)) for t in remove_nan]
df.columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(remove_nan)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   tech_one                      ... tech_four       etc       mtc
        ch0       ch1       ch2  ...       ch5         _         _
         b0        b0        b0  ...                              
0 -0.969233  0.746873  0.253076  ...  0.087689  0.874305  0.380449
1  0.387685 -0.382714 -1.043338  ... -1.684973  1.346454 -0.437792
2 -1.300301  0.164648 -0.032736  ...  1.198207  1.608662 -0.818090
[3 rows x 13 columns]
```