# Multiindexed columns with missing levels in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a column-multiindexed dataframe, but I don't quite get how to handle columns with missing levels. As a MWE, I create a dummy dataframe like this

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     np.random.rand(2, 4),
   ...:     columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2]])
   ...: )
   ...: df[('C', np.nan)] = 3
   ...: df
Out[4]: 
          A                   B             C
        1.0       2.0       1.0       2.0 NaN
0  0.484498  0.218928  0.480720  0.530619   3
1  0.789152  0.687612  0.953487  0.926798   3
```

Notice the last line of the code, which creates a new column with a single level and a *padding* nan (I do this because that's what `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` does when passed tuples of different length).

I can access the first column with no problems,

```
In [5]: df[('A', 1)]
Out[5]: 
0    0.484498
1    0.789152
Name: (A, 1.0), dtype: float64
```

but when I try to access the last column *in the exact same way it was created*

```
df[('C', np.nan)]
```

I get a KeyError

```
In [6]: df[('C', np.nan)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df[('C', np.nan)]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dlsproc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3504, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3502 if is_single_key:
   3503     if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
-> 3504         return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   3505     indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506     if is_integer(indexer):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dlsproc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3555, in DataFrame._getitem_multilevel(self, key)
   3553 def _getitem_multilevel(self, key):
   3554     # self.columns is a MultiIndex
-> 3555     loc = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3556     if isinstance(loc, (slice, np.ndarray)):
   3557         new_columns = self.columns[loc]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dlsproc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py:2882, in MultiIndex.get_loc(self, key, method)
   2880 if keylen == self.nlevels and self.is_unique:
   2881     try:
-> 2882         return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2883     except TypeError:
   2884         # e.g. test_partial_slicing_with_multiindex partial string slicing
   2885         loc, _ = self.get_loc_level(key, list(range(self.nlevels)))

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dlsproc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:779, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dlsproc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dlsproc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1832, in pandas._libs.hashtable.UInt64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1841, in pandas._libs.hashtable.UInt64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 12
```

Any clue?

Cheers.

Comment: `df['C'][np.nan]` seems to work

Comment: The issue with `NaN` is that they are bad to use as keys: `np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`

Comment: @mozway, good point...

Answer (score 1):

One hack with replace missing values in columns by empty string:

```
print (df.rename(columns= lambda x: '' if pd.isna(x) else x)[('C','')])
0    3
1    3
Name: (C, ), dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `df['C']`, this will select that series:

```
   NaN
0    3
1    3
```

Or `df['C'][np.nan]` to get just the values:

```
0    4
1    4
Name: nan, dtype: int64
```

(NB: This only works if there is only one NaN column under C in the multi-index, otherwise you get `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but I'm finally going with the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68940748). Essentially, replacing the `np.nan`s with empty strings is easier to handle. At dataframe creation,

```
df[('C', '')] = 3
```

and then

```
In [7]: df[('C', '')]
Out[7]: 
0    3
1    3
Name: (C, ), dtype: int64
```

Comment: This was pretty much @jezrael's answer.

Comment: Fair enough: +1!!  The suggestion in the referenced post seemed to me like a less hacky approach (because you build the dataframe that way), but yes, same idea.